# get keywords in input and store them in an array with jquery

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how I could store a query such as this in an array : `"hello again world"`

the keywords would be in an input field with  id =  status, and would have to be split by " ". Also how would I escape certain words and characters in this array as matched by the words/characters in the array `stopwords`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//split the words by space
var keywds = $("#status").val().split(" ");
$.each(keywds,function(i,val){
   //check if its an empty string 
   if($.trim(val) == ""){
      keywds.splice(i);
   }//Check if it's in stopwords
   else if($.inArray(val,stopwords)>= 0)       
   {
      keywds.splice(i);
   }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pfQnt/

Comment: this is an excellent answer, but small problem. what if the query had more than one space, ie : "hello      world" :p

Answer (score 0):

```
// get value and split the string
var keywords = $('#status').val().split(' ');
// get all keywords who are not in the array stopwords
var result = [];
for (var index in keywords) {
    if ($.inArray(keywords[index], stopwords) == -1) {
        result.push(keywords[index]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of your input with the `getElementById` method and the element's `value` property:

```
var keywords = document.getElementById('status').value;
```

Once you have that, you can just use the `split` method to separate by spaces:

```
keywords = keywords.split(' ');
```

And you can have an array always standing by, to hold your keywords:

```
var stopwords = [];
```

Finally, you're going to want to check with each new keyword before you insert it:

```
var addUnique = function (keyword) {
        var i = stopwords.length;
        while (i) {
            i -= 1;
            if (keyword === stopwords[i]) {
                return;
            }
        }
        stopwords[stopwords.length] = keyword;
    },
    addMany = function (keywords) {
        var i = keywords.length;
        while (i) {
            i -= 1;
            addUnique(keywords[i]);
        }
    };
```

The final script will look something like this:

```
var keyword_form = document.getElementById('yourForm'),
    keyword_input = document.getElementById('status'),
    stopwords = [],
    addUnique = function (keyword) {
        var i = stopwords.length;
        while (i) {
            i -= 1;
            if (keyword === stopwords[i]) {
                return;
            }
        }
        stopwords[stopwords.length] = keyword;
    },
    addMany = function (keywords) {
        var i = keywords.length;
        while (i) {
            i -= 1;
            addUnique(keywords[i]);
        }
    };

keyword_form.onsubmit = function () {
    var keywords = keyword_input.value.split(' ');
    addMany(keywords);
};
```